# Open app from gmail with my url scheme as a link

Tags: ios, swift

I declared a url scheme in my ios app, myapp so that my app will be able to open from another apps like sms and gmail.

For sms app, this works fine. SMS detects myapp:// and shows it as a link. On clicking, it opens my app. But this fails for gmail. When I receive an email with the same url in gmail app. It fails to detect it as a link, which results to unable to open my app.

How can I achieve deep linking my app with gmail as well?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a url scheme the third party app like Gmail would also have to add support for your url scheme. Maybe Universal Links can work in your case? https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/